# How to replace multiple patterns without stepping on each other on hex file? (sed/awk or any other command)

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have to replace some characters in an hex file according to a character table. To simplify the problem let's say I have this input:

```
0x1A 0x44 0x2C
```

and my table says that:

```
0x1A=K
0X44=u
0X2C=?
```

So the expected result would be 'Ku?' without quotes.

If I run this command

```
cat file.hex | sed 's/\x1A/K/g;\x44/u/g;\x2C/?/g'
```

I get ?u? instead of Ku?, since the third sed command steps over the first. In this case I could reorder them, but I have to do about 40 commands and there's no order that doesn't overlap anything.

How can I make sed not replace the same part of the string twice? or which command can do multiple replacements in parallel?

Comment: As a belated observation, `sed` is perfectly capable of opening and reading a file (and if it wasn't, `sed <file.hex` would cause the shell to open it and feed it to `sed` on standard input).  You have a [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 'y/\x1A\x44\x2C/Ku?/' file
```

Comment: It's extrange I could not find this or the tr command while googling, maybe I'm just bad with reges words, anyways either the tr command or this is what I needed thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple to understand solution using only a Bash array for ASCII

```
declare -a tbl
tbl[0x1A]=K
tbl[0X44]=u
tbl[0X2C]=?

while read line; do
  for c in $line; do
    let r=c
    echo -n "${tbl[$r]}"
    done
  echo 
done < file.hex
```

For a binary replacement, consider tr.  Here is the idea

```
tr '\032D,' Ku? < file.binary
```

Comment: Does this work for binary files? or only for text ones?

Comment: Text.  If you want character for character (binary), consider the "tr" command.

Comment: Wow that command seems exactly what I needed, I'll try it and see how it works, thanks!

Comment: You can have binary in Bash with C-style strings like `$'\x1A'`.

Answer (score 1):

A generalized solution is to have a mapping table.  Then just do one global replacement, where each string which is found in the mapping table is replaced with its mapping.

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { %map = ("\x1A"=>"K", "\x44"=>"u", "\x2C"=>"?");
        $k = join("|", keys %map); }
    s/($k)/$map{$1}/g'
```

If you have overlapping strings of different length, you want to make sure the long ones come before the short ones in `$k`, but for this simple demo, I just joined them with no regard for the ordering.